# why does my mesh render on top of UI?

Tags: unity, rendering, mesh, unity-ui

I've got some UI elements and a 3D mesh imported from blender. I've tried stuff like sorting layers, so that I render my 3D mesh below a canvas UI element(side panel), for which I put my 3D mesh prefab under the UI layer, but, my mesh always ends up rendering on top. How can I render my mesh below the UI element? This is similar to the TMP(Text Mesh Pro) issue I have seen on the web, but, I already have front and back materials for the mesh, so I can't use TMP's distance field overlay shader.

Here's the basic hierarchy:

parent
|
----->myprefabMesh  (on layer UI)
|
|---->UISidePanel  (on Layer side panel)

Sorting layer order:
-- UI
-- LayerSidePanel

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of your current set up including scene hierarchy?

Comment: I don't think I'd be able to effectively do that, since I don't entirely own the project, I'm really sorry. But, I added some more information

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why your Mesh is on UI layer, but to achieve simple UI over 3D gameobjects, you just have to place your UI as child of a "Screen Space - Overlay" canvas and your 3D gameobjects somewhere else. It should work !

Comment: What display mode are you using for your UI Canvas? In Screen Space Overlay mode, the UI will draw over everything. But in Screen Space Camera or World Space modes, it gets sorted/occluded by depth like other geometry, so you might just be drawing your UI too far from the camera.

Comment: @DMGregory , thanks that was it, the UI was in screen space camera, thanks a lot, I changed to overlay and ddone! haha, thanks again

Comment: @SebastienServouze,  thanks that was it, the UI was in screen space camera, thanks a lot, I changed to overlay and ddone! haha, thanks again

Comment: @DMGregory, but, what would we do if we'd like to sandwitch the 3D mesh like in between 2 UI elements so that the top most would occlude but the last most wouldn't? Would sorting layers come to play?

Comment: @SebastienServouze , but, what would we do if we'd like to sandwitch the 3D mesh like in between 2 UI elements so that the top most would occlude but the last most wouldn't? Would sorting layers come to play?

Comment: If you've solved your problem, be sure to post the solution as an answer. And in future when troubleshooting UI issues, be sure to provide complete information about how to recreate the problem: including your Canvas settings.

Comment: @DMGregory , sure, but, can you give me a hint on the side question I've posted in just the most recent comment to you?

Comment: That's a different question that should be asked in a different post. Sorting Layers apply ONLY to 2D/UI content, not to Mesh Renderers, so you would need a different solution for that. The exact shape the solution would take may depend on the final look you want to achieve, so you should include visual examples to help us understand your end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was having is as mentioned above, I was having the canvas in screen space camera mode rather than in screen space overlay mode.